# Show that every unitary matrix $A$ can be written as $(H+iI)^{-1}(H-iI)$ where H is a hermitian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am able to prove its converse. But I am finding it difficult to approach this problem. I guess there is an explicit construction of such a matrix $H$ in terms of $A$.

Comment: For an approach, start from the finish line: You want $(H+iI)^{-1} (H-iI) = A$. If such $H$ is to exist, can you express it with $A$?

Comment: @Ranc that was really simple. I don't know how I missed it.